# A CTE with DENSE_RANK, should i use a Subselect within OR a JOIN Condition

Tags: t-sql

In the original table there are a lot of records. Is it better to filter within the CTE (example B) or should this be done in the JOIN condition (example A). Or is it possibly all the same, both are equally good/fast?

I guess in the CTE the whole table would have to be prefiltered first and in the JOIN only the corresponding records would be affected.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(
    orderid   int        NOT NULL,
    orderdate datetime   NOT NULL,
    empid     int        NOT NULL,
    custid    varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    qty       int        NOT NULL
);
-- in original lots of data
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(30001, '20020802', 3, 'A', 10);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(10001, '20021224', 1, 'A', 12);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(10005, '20021224', 1, 'B', 20);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(40001, '20030109', 4, 'A', 40);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(10006, '20030118', 1, 'C', 14);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(20001, '20030212', 2, 'B', 12);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(40005, '20040212', 4, 'A', 10);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(20002, '20040216', 2, 'C', 20);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(30003, '20040418', 3, 'B', 15);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(30004, '20020418', 3, 'C', 22);
INSERT INTO @Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty) VALUES(30007, '20020907', 3, 'D', 30);

-- example A
WITH CTE_
AS(
    SELECT 
         orderid  
        ,orderdate
        ,empid    
        ,custid   
        ,qty      
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY orderid) AS [Ranking]
    FROM @Orders
)

SELECT
    d.*
FROM CTE_ AS d
WHERE d.[Ranking] = 1;

-------------------------------------
-- example B
WITH CTE_
AS(
    SELECT 
         orderid  
        ,orderdate
        ,empid    
        ,custid   
        ,qty 
    FROM(
        SELECT 
             orderid  
            ,orderdate
            ,empid    
            ,custid   
            ,qty      
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY orderid) AS [Ranking]
        FROM @Orders
    ) AS d
    WHERE d.[Ranking] = 1
)

SELECT
    d.*
FROM CTE_ AS d
```

Comment: CTE is actually an instantiated view, so they should result in the exactly same query plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it's better to filter within the CTE (`example B`), especially in case of your tables have indexes in filter conditions, these indexes could be applied to be pre-filtered data first. Since a CTE is a temporary view, it can't have indexes, so in case of `example A`, your main query could not use indexes (if have) for filter condition in `WHERE` statement.